# Location std-out logs in Tomcat Web App from Azure

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Web Apps, and am trying to debug my Java Application which is inside a Tomcat container.

When I go to the "Log Files" folder using Visual Studio or FTP or Kudo, I only see the following

1. localhost
2. catalina
3. host-manager

[image]

I do not see std-out. Many lines in my application use `System.out.println()` (I am not looking to replace them all with a Logger at this stage)

How can I see std-out?
I tried adding as many logs as I could in App Service Logs, but this didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I configured my WebApp with Java and Tomcat on Azure portal as the figure below.

[image]

So you can find the `logging.properties` file of Tomcat 9.0.14 at the path of Kudu console `D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-9.0.14\conf` as the figure below.

[image]

You can see that used the default logging of Tomcat, so these console output of `System.out.println` will not be written into these logging files of `D:\home\LogFiles\Application`.

However, I tried to write some codes as below in the `index.jsp` of `D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT\`.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.logging.*" %>

<%
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Hello");
    out.println("Hello, world from webapps/ROOT/index.jsp on Tomcat on cloud.<br>");
    System.out.println("System.out >> Hello, world from webapps/ROOT/index.jsp on Tomcat on cloud.");
    logger.warning("Logger Level Warning >> Hello, world from webapps/ROOT/index.jsp on Tomcat on cloud. ");
    logger.info("Logger Level Info >> Hello, world from webapps/ROOT/index.jsp on Tomcat on cloud. ");
    logger.fine("Logger Level Fine >> Hello, world from webapps/ROOT/index.jsp on Tomcat on cloud. ");
%>
```

Then, I can see the logs of only logging level `warning` and `info` be written into `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\catalina.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.2019-08-19.log`, as the figure below, because the logging level priority is `SEVERE > WARNING > INFO > CONFIG > FINE > FINER > FINEST`.

[image]

Due to the [`File System Restrictions/Considerations`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#file-system-restrictionsconsiderations) of Azure WebApp, except `D:\home`, you can not do the write operation in the other path.

So if you want to write some logs into a file, please use `java.util.logging.Logger` instead of `System.out`, or to use other logging framework like `log4j` or `slf4j`.

Hope it helps.